# How to bind string array from FormData when using GET method in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I have the following DTO which I want to call via GET:

```
    [Route("/documents")]
    public class Documents : IReturn<DocumentsResult>
    {
        public string[] IDs { get; set; }
    }
```

A simple `Service`:

```
    public DocumentsResult Get(Documents doc)
    {
       //implementation not relevant
    }
```

When trying to call with many IDs using `JsonServiceClient.Get()` method, I get BadRequest because the query string is too long.

**How can I ensure that the IDs property is bound from FormData?**

Comment: imo, if you have that much data to put into a query string, sounds like the more pragmatic approach would be to use POST or reconsider the overall request/data input design. Any specific reason it needs to be a GET request?

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to have this many IDs because this is adapting to existing client API expectations which require this. It does not need to be GET, it is GET because the operation is GetDocumentsByIds. But changing this to POST would feel like a hack.

Comment: How long does that query string get before it starts to break? There are hard limits to query string length that you'll eventually run into. Parameterizing the request path probably isn't good, that has length limits too, and you can't use a request body with GET.

Comment: I realize there are query string length limitations. I have not tried when this starts to break. I will probably go with POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **GET** request can only use the QueryString so does not have FormData. The limit you're hitting is likely an IIS/ASP.NET limit on queryStrings (there are no explicit usage limits in ServiceStack). So you can try and increase the limits on GET requests in your Web.config with:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

Otherwise your solution is to either use a **POST** so the request is sent through the request body or batch the requests using a **GET** into more manageable chunks that doesn't exceed the [default limit of 2048 chars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxquerystringlength.aspx).